# how to show simple_form vertically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

```
= simple_form_for @session, :as => 'session', :url => session_path do |form|
  %form
    .form-group
      .form
        = form.input :email

      .form
        = form.input :password  

      .form-actions
        %button.btn.btn-primary{type: "submit"} Log in
```

above sample generates the following horizontal view, where input fields are to the right of labels

*Email     [input]

*Password  [input]

Is it possible to show them vertically on top of each other, so labels are above input fields? How can it be achieved?

*Email
[input]

*Password

[input]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
= simple_form_for @session, :as => 'session', :url => session_path do |form|
  %form
    .form-group
      .form
         %div
           = form.label :email
           = form.email_field :email
         %div
           = form.label :password
           = form.password_field :password
```

Comment: what happens if the field is first_name, can I write = form.first_name_field :first_name or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @igor, no, you will most likely have to write either `=form.input_field :first_name` or `=form.input :first_name` or `=form.text_field :first_name` (every one will work). Basically this all stated in `gem`'s docs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the github page:
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

```
<%= f.input :username, label: 'Your username please' %>
```

Will make the label a block element, instead of inline_label.

Or you can specify the label and the input field seperately:

```
<%= f.label :username %>
<br/>
<%= f.input_field :username %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
  %label Email*
  %div
    = form.input :email

  %label Password*
  %div
    = form.input :password
```

Comment: it shows the labels, but still the same problem as before showing horizontally *Email [input] below